# I want to use regex to extract nine digits from a string in Blueprism

Tags: regex, blueprism

I have the following string:

```
ABCD/SESSION REMARKS/SESSION REMARKS_002FT2213700215_ /CODTYPTR/049 //R101841246/058  Session 220517080                                                  REF: 02024741031486605002FT221
```

And i want to extract the nine digits that from "R101841246".

I have tried using ***Extract Regex in Utility - Strings of Blueprism***, using the regex pattern `(?<Lower>\d{9})` but the code is extracting 221370021, the first nine digits from `SESSION REMARKS_002FT2213700215_`.

I need a regex that will strictly extract nine consecutive digits and ignore occurrences where there is over nine digits

Comment: Try `\bR(?<Lower>\d{9})\b`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
\bR-?(?<Lower>\d{9})\b
```

Here, it matches

- `\b` - a word boundary
- `R` - an `R` letter
- `-?` - an optional hyphen
- `(?<Lower>\d{9})` - nine digits captured into Group "Lower"
- `\b` - a word boundary.

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/0kmK2m/1).

Answer (score 0):

here is one way do it

```
(?<=\/\/).(\d){9}(?=\/)
```

https://regex101.com/r/TYnSuP/1

(?<=//) : look behind for //
. : then any character
(\d){9} : capture the 9 digits
(?=/) : and lookahead /